# why can't I declare a function in cpp?

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num, prime, a, x, y, times;
int exponentiation(num, prime){
    times = 0;
    while (a % prime == 0){
        times += prime;
        a = a / prime;
    }
    if(times > 0){
        cout << prime << "^" << times;
    }
}


int main()
{       
    cin >> a;
    
    exponentiation(a, 2);
    
    for(x = 3; x <= 10000; x++){
        for(y = 3; y <= x; y++){
            if(x % y == 0)
            break;
            else if (x == y + 1)
            exponentiation(a, x);
        }
    }   
return 0;
}
```

I was trying to factorize numbers with cpp and came up with the idea of declaring a function to figure out how many times a prime number can divide my number so that I'll just have to put all the prime numbers in to get results like 2(prime numers)^3(returned by the function)

However the compiler said that my function cannot be used as a function for some reason. Can someone tell me what's the problem? Is it the function or the main part where things went wrong?

Comment: You might want to declare some datatypes for your parameters.

Comment: thats just not the right syntax to declare a function. `int exponentiation(num, prime){` -> `int exponentiation(int num,int prime){`. Voting to close as typo. Also the function either needs return type `void` or return something

Comment: btw when asking about a compiler error you should include the compiler error in the question

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Comment: TBF, ti's not a million miles off the really old-style C function syntax, which would have been `int exponentiation(num, prime) int num; int prime; { /*...*/ }`. But C++ is not C, and it's been several decades since that style was supplanted in C by `int exponentiation(int num, int prime) { /*...*/ }`.

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems with the declaration syntax for functions.

```
int num, prime;
int exponentiation(num, prime){
```

is written

```
int exponentiation(int num, int prime){
```

Comment: Side note: in old style `C` something similar to invalid code [is possible](https://godbolt.org/z/WWG7d4vjs). This is probably source of confusion.